# Fill up the empty space of a FlowLayout

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, layout-manager, flowlayout

I have a flowlayout panel which has a textfield inside. Although the textfield is not that wide but I want to place components on the next line. How do I fill the remaining space with an empty box?

Comment: use a LayoutManager that does what you want

Comment: In order to place components to the extreme left using `FlowLayout` what you can do is this, `panelObject.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));`, that will allow it to place components from extreme left, not from middle as the case is with no argument `FlowLayout()` constructor.

Comment: Your comment solved my problem in a matter of 15 keystrokes, @nIcEcOw. Thanks very much. Such a helpful comment deserves to be posted as an answer. :-)

Comment: @OleV.V.: Glad the comment, did helped you in some way. For the rest, You're MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need more deterministic control over the way your components are laid out, you should consider using a different layout manager such as BoxLayout, GridLayout, or GridBagLayout.  You may be able to trick FlowLayout into doing what you want, but what happens if the user resizes the window?  Or changes their font DPI at the OS level?  Instead of having your components be on different lines as a side effect of putting dummy components into a FlowLayout, consider expressing the above/below relationship more explicitly with a layout manager that has those concepts built in (e.g. `GridBagConstraints.gridy`).

Comment: Yep, agree 1+. Also @Soler: realize that you can nest JPanels, each using its own layout manager and by doing so create complex GUI's but only using simple layouts.

Answer (score 3):

Fill it with empty `JPanel`:

```
new JPanel();
```

Comment: But I have a JLabel already inside the panel which is currently centred for some weird reason, after playing about I found out the more labels I add the more that particular label shifts to the left.

I want to shift the label all the way to the left but I need to somehow add some empty space, JPanel doesn't seem to work for this.

Comment: no - that's not even a hack (however weird the problem is described)

Answer (score 1):

No need to overcomplicate things here. This simple solution works (at least it did for me):

```
panelObject.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
```

This will flush the components to the left on a computer with left-to-right default reading direction (it’s called orientation), and the opposite way on computers with reading direction from the right. Thus it lends itself well to internationalization. If you want the components to the left on all computers (and the empty space to the right), use `new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT)`.

Thanks to @nIcE cOw for suggesting this solution in a comment under the question, and for allowing me to post it as an answer.